# PHP json_decode google cloud messaging handle errors

Tags: php

```
{"multicast_id":6500496951237632198,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

How to get value "NotRegistered" form this json message.

if print `$obj->failure` will get 1.

if print `$obj->results` only get Array.

Comment: `$obj->results[0]->error` results is an array of length=1, its only element is another object. instead of using `print` try using `print_r` or `var_dump` with objects and arrays

Comment: ok, this work for me

Comment: Hi @Octopus, This came up in my triage queue, and your comment is good, but it sounds like it should be an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use something like:

```php
print $obj->results[0]->error;
```